# Displaying Different Images in a Horizontal scroll view that comes from server

Tags: android, json, image, server

I am new to android. I want to implement images that are horizontally scrollable and each image has its own click listener. The image comes from the server. I have the url of the image. the screen shot clearly describes what is my requirement.
Link is http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html
Help is really appreciated.. thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you try recyclerView with horizontalLayoutManager ?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: can you give me a code sample. that can help me in implementing that

Comment: I would recommend doing a bit of learning about recyclerView , its slightly complicated, I am sorry I don't have any specific code to share right now! I ll make one share it asap.  but try some tutorials about recyclerView on youtube before you implement, its a bit tricky for beginners  ...

Comment: try this sample https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=recyclerview

Comment: @Dev.. I tried implementing that. but was not able to succeed.. It would be really helpful if you can gv me a running code

Comment: can you share the code which you tried ? we can debug that relativly easy  I guess

Comment: Actually i had gone through the GIT hub code. It is using an fragment. But i am using it an activity. i have an existing activity in which i want to show my requirement. That why i am saying you to share a running code.